# Greasemonkey script to replace image url

Tags: image, url, firefox, replace, greasemonkey

I will appreciate some help with this, I have this image src:

```
https://images.example.com/150x150/archive/2020-05-01/filename.jpg
```

And I want to replace it with this:

```
https://example.com/files/large/2020-05-01/filename.jpg
```

This will let me view the bigger image instead of the thumb...

I've tried this, but didn't work:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
var images = links[i];
images.src= images.src.replace("images.example.com/150x150/archive", "example.com/files/large");
}
```

Is this possible?
Many thanks!!
Regads,

Comment: OK... yes, you're right, it works... but this don't replace the image url, it changes out when you open the image... I need it to be replace in the page... it's clear enough? Thanks!

Comment: Can you help me out @Thefourthbird? Thanks!!

Comment: Currently, the url of the image changes after the Javascript is done running. What do you mean by open the image? Can you update the question with the code that does not work for you?

Comment: Currently doesn't change the image on the page... it only change it if you open it apart...
http://porras.com.ar/google_ex.png

Comment: Please note that the script can change the image `src` at the time the scripts runs. In JS generated pages, like Google, if the image tag is created later & after the GM script has run, the script in the current form has no effect on it. Script would require more code to look for changes and re-apply image `src` change.

Comment: Exactly @erosman, that's what I'm looking for...

Comment: Just noticed this script should run before an AJAX search results display... @Thefourthbird

Comment: @zirucweb So now it works? It runs after all other things have run so it does not get overridden?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, is working now... I just added `window.addEventListener("load", function() {` at the beg and `}, false);` and the end... the problem now is with pagination, because it's apply only to actual page, but when you go to page 2 is off... Any clue on how to fix that? Thank a lot!!!